# Error Navigating to the product category page

Tags: magento2.4

I am facing this error while navigating to the product categories page on Magento 2.4.1

Stacktrace here: https://pastebin.com/SJmEDkrG

StackExchange won't let me paste the stack here as it thinks this is spam.

Can someone please help understand why does this error occurs? I'm kinda new to Magento. I am running the Porto theme on Magento 2.4 installation on AWS EC2 instance.

Comment: What is the actual error? You're only showing the stacktrace in the paste bin.

Comment: When I click on the product category link, it says "There has been an error processing your request" with log record number. And pasted above is the log record contents